# How to prevent the user for putting pins on map too close.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I use this protocol method to get coordinates where user drops a pin.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState 
...
```

In this method I check if this pin is dropped too close to some other pin on map and when this happens I want to move pin programmatically 100 meters far from that pin.
But I don't know how and what is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This method you can use to get the distance from other pin annotation

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

Comment: I already use this method to get distance and when I catch that it is less than 100 meters far I want to move it programmatically. I don't know how to move pin.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the distance less than 100m between new one and all other pins
('MKMapView' 'annotations' property ).
To calculate distance between each pins you can use `CLLocation`

```
CLLocation *pointALocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitudeA longitude:longitudeA];
CLLocation *pointBLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitudeB longitude:longitudeB];

double distanceInMeters = [pointALocation getDistanceFrom:pointBLocation];
```

Than block pin adding/moving If this distance less than 100

Comment: Yes I know how to calculate distance but how to "Block moving"?